# If statement not processing - Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm writing a tic tac toe problem.

The `TicTacToe`  class works fine, but the first if statement in my Main class isn't processing. The `TicTacToe` class isn't what's wrong, because when Player 1 wins the `oNew.checkWinner(1)` returns true. (I checked by placing `System.out.println(oNew.checkWinner(1));` right before the if statement).

But then it doesn't pass into the if statement to break the while loop and just continues on. It does the same with the first else if too.

The odd part is it works just fine for the 2nd if statement and 2nd else if statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        TicTacToe oNew = new TicTacToe();
        String champ = "";
        boolean hasWon = false;

        oNew.getMove();
        while(hasWon == false){
            oNew.setMove(1);
            oNew.getMove();
            if (oNew.checkWinner(1) == true){
                champ = "Player 1 wins.";
                hasWon = true;
            }
            else if(oNew.checkCatsGame() == true){
                champ = "Draw";
                hasWon = true;
            }
            oNew.setMove(2);
            oNew.getMove();
            if (oNew.checkWinner(2) == true){
                champ = "Player 2 wins.";
                hasWon = true;
            }
            else if(oNew.checkCatsGame() == true){
                champ = "Draw";
                hasWon = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(champ);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to leave the loop when one of the conditions is true, add either `break` or `continue` (if you don't, the statements following the first if-else-if block are executed before the current iteration of the loop ends and the condition of the loop is checked again) :

```
if (oNew.checkWinner(1)){
    champ = "Player 1 wins.";
    hasWon = true;
    continue;
}
else if(oNew.checkCatsGame()){
    champ = "Draw";
    hasWon = true;
    continue;
}
```

- continue would end the current iteration, and the while loop will be exited once the condition is tested for the next iteration.
- break will terminate the loop regardless of the value of `hasWon`.